# Writing to csv file - python 3.7

Tags: python, pandas, csv, wireshark

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xu0F8.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxN1W.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r05V.png)I got some csv files. The file names are as filename1.in.csv and filename1.out.csv , filename2.in.csv and filename2.out.csv. These files are in folders and sub folders. I'm trying to calculate some statistical values of .in.csv files separately and .out.csv files separately. But at the end all these needs to get written into one csv file (known as OutputFile in my code) row by row with headings. Each row gets the name of the input file as className along with calculated values. I have attached an image of a csv file that I take as the input (inFile) to calculate statistical values. I am not getting the desired output. gives `NameError: maxTimeIn, minTimeIn, stdTimeIn, qual1TimeIn, qual2TimeIn, maxLenIn, minLenIn, stdLenIn, qual1LenIn, qua12LenIn, maxTimeOut, minTimeOut, stdTimeOut, qual1TimeOut, qual2TimeOut, maxLenOut, minLenOut, stdLenOut, qual1LenOut, qua12LenOut, className not defined`.
I am new to Python, so I am not sure if my code will give the output as required, Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import csv

startdir= '.'
suffix= '.csv'
for root,dirs, files, in os.walk(startdir):
    for name in files:
        if not name.endswith(suffix):
            continue
        inFile = os.path.join(root,name)

        data = pd.read_csv(inFile)

        base = os.path.basename(inFile)
        className = os.path.splitext(base)[0]

        if inFile.endswith('.in.csv'):

            maxTimeIn = data['frame.time_delta_displayed'].max()
            minTimeIn = data['frame.time_delta_displayed'].min()
            stdTimeIn = data['frame.time_delta_displayed'].std()
            qual1TimeIn = data['frame.time_delta_displayed'].quantile(0.25)
            qual2TimeIn = data['frame.time_delta_displayed'].quantile(0.5)

            maxLenIn = data['frame.len'].max()
            minLenIn = data['frame.len'].min()
            stdLenIn = data['frame.len'].std()
            qual1LenIn = data['frame.len'].quantile(0.25)
            qua12LenIn = data['frame.len'].quantile(0.5)

        if inFile.endswith('.out.csv'):

            maxTimeOut = data['frame.time_delta_displayed'].max()
            minTimeOut = data['frame.time_delta_displayed'].min()
            stdTimeOut = data['frame.time_delta_displayed'].std()
            qual1TimeOut = data['frame.time_delta_displayed'].quantile(0.25)
            qual2TimeOut = data['frame.time_delta_displayed'].quantile(0.5)

            maxLenOut = data['frame.len'].max()
            minLenOut = data['frame.len'].min()
            stdLenOut = data['frame.len'].std()
            qual1LenOut = data['frame.len'].quantile(0.25)
            qua12LenOut = data['frame.len'].quantile(0.5)

            csvData = [['maxTimeIn', 'minTimeIn', 'stdTimeIn', 'q1TimeIn', 'q2TimeIn', 'maxLenIn', 'minLenIn', 'stdLenIn', 'q1LenIn', 'q2LenIn', 'maxTimeOut', 'minTimeOut', 'stdTimeOut', 'q1TimeOut', 'q2TimeOut', 'maxLenOut', 'minLenOut', 'stdLenOut', 'q1LenOut', 'q2LenOut','activity'],
                       [maxTimeIn, minTimeIn, stdTimeIn, qual1TimeIn, qual2TimeIn, maxLenIn, minLenIn, stdLenIn, qual1LenIn, qua12LenIn, maxTimeOut, minTimeOut, stdTimeOut, qual1TimeOut, qual2TimeOut, maxLenOut, minLenOut, stdLenOut, qual1LenOut, qua12LenOut, className]]

        with open('/root/Desktop/OutputFile.csv','w') as csvFile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
            writer.writerows(csvData)

        csvFile.close()
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/Tracebacks.  Just copy the text, paste it in your question and format it as code.

Comment: @wwii I have now pasted my code in the question itself. Thanks

Comment: If you post images of csv data, how likely do you think someone is going to spend time recreating the data by hand to try and help you. If you provide enough info, including data that can be copied and pasted into an editor and reproduces thr problem, the people will be more likely to give it a go. Please read [mcve]. Also, you should always provide the complete Traceback, formatted as code.

Comment: you should substitute the second if with an `elif inFile.endswith('.out.csv'):`

Comment: How about fixing the indentation at `csvData`, it should be under the `for` loop not `if` statement.

Comment: The exception message you included in your question does not make sense. When a list of names is evaluated and All of the names are not defined, the exception message will only complain about the first name that is not defined. For example,  `[a,b,c,d,e]` if none of those names are defined the message is just - `Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "C:\tmp.py", line 25, in <module> 
    a = [a,b,c,d,e] 
NameError: name 'a' is not defined`

Comment: @wwii sorry the error message is Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/AppAct/stackflow.py", line 47, in <module>
    [maxTimeIn, minTimeIn, stdTimeIn, qual1TimeIn, qual2TimeIn, maxLenIn, minLenIn, stdLenIn, qual1LenIn, qua12LenIn, maxTimeOut, minTimeOut, stdTimeOut, qual1TimeOut, qual2TimeOut, maxLenOut, minLenOut, stdLenOut, qual1LenOut, qua12LenOut, className]]
NameError: name 'maxTimeIn' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code where I used `pathlib` instead of `os.path` and refactored functions to utilize Pandas methods:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd


def prepare_values(df):
    df_columns = ['frame.time_delta_displayed', 'frame.len']
    df_values = []
    for col in df_columns:
        df_values += [
            df[col].max(),
            df[col].min(),
            df[col].std(),
            df[col].quantile(0.25),
            df[col].quantile(0.5),
        ]
    return df_values


source_dir = Path('stat')

in_data = []
for file in source_dir.glob('**/*.in.csv'):
    activity = {'activity': file.stem.split('.')[0]}
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    cols = ['maxTimeIn', 'minTimeIn', 'stdTimeIn', 'q1TimeIn', 'q2TimeIn',
            'maxLenIn', 'minLenIn', 'stdLenIn', 'q1LenIn', 'q2LenIn']
    values = prepare_values(df)
    file_data = {**activity, **dict(zip(cols, values))}
    in_data.append(file_data)

out_data = []
for file in source_dir.glob('**/*.out.csv'):
    activity = {'activity': file.stem.split('.')[0]}
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    cols = ['maxTimeOut', 'minTimeOut', 'stdTimeOut', 'q1TimeOut', 'q2TimeOut',
            'maxLenOut', 'minLenOut', 'stdLenOut', 'q1LenOut', 'q2LenOut']
    values = prepare_values(df)
    file_data = {**activity, **dict(zip(cols, values))}
    out_data.append(file_data)

in_df = pd.DataFrame(in_data)
out_df = pd.DataFrame(out_data)
all_df = in_df.join(out_df.set_index('activity'), on='activity', how='outer')

all_df.dropna(subset=df_all.columns.tolist()[1:], how='all', inplace=True)
all_df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
all_df.to_csv('all_data.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks. I posted it as a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56931069/remove-letters-and-signs-from-csv-file-python-3-7

Comment: sorry to bother you again. Just wondering why the rows with only '0' zeros are not getting deleted from the csv file. You have written dropna command, but rows with only zeros are still there. how can these get deleted? https://fil.email/8W45yvsi

Comment: that should be posted as a new question. add the data within the question and ask for how to delete rows with zeros. I'll try to answer there.

Comment: Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56959036/delete-rows-with-zeros I added