# Remove letters and signs from csv file - python 3.7

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, csv

I got a CSV file with a column named `activity` which has data like:

```
instv2-02_00001_20190517235008
instv2 (9)
Insti2(3)
Fbstt1_00001_20190517131933
```

I need to remove numbers and any other signs (example: _) from the names in the 'activity' column only.
That means need to keep just the letters. 
for example `instv3-02_00001_20190517235157`, 
`instv1-02_00000_20190517234840`, instv1 (4)...etc all need to be renamed/replaced as instv. How can I do this in a Python script?

Comment: Take a look at `re` python module for regex.

Comment: Please post a few lines from the csv file along with the desired output?

Comment: you can use this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/HtIVPW/1). `re.findall("([A-Za-z]+)",string)`

Comment: @Nick thanks. I have add an image with only few lines. instv3-02_00001_20190517235157,  instv1-02_00000_20190517234840, instv1 (4)..etc all need to replace as instv ... Fbstt4_00006_20190517132330, Fbstt4 (3) etc all need to replace as Fbstt...

Comment: See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: actual values in the CSV file will be most helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pandas`, load the CSV file and apply a regex replacement on the `activity` column values.

Try this code:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv')
df['activity'] = df['activity'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'^([a-zA-Z]+).*', r'\1', x))
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

and if it is related to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56890270/writing-to-csv-file-python-3-7), then you just need to 
import re and change the last line of the solution to be like:

```
import re

# ...

all_df['activity'] = all_df['activity'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'^([a-zA-Z]+).*', r'\1', x))
all_df.to_csv('all_data.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: @Hasa you may need to import `re`

Answer (score 1):

Using `re` module and builtin `open` function:

```
import re

with open('Alldata10.csv', 'r') as file_r, open('Alldata10_revised.csv', 'w') as file_w:
    for line in file_r:
        line = line.split(',')
        line[0] = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]+', '', line[0])
        line = ','.join(line)
        file_w.write(line)
```