# Delete rows with zeros

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I got a csv file with different statistical values calculated. NA values have been  replaced as zeros. How can I delete rows that has only zeros using a python script.

```
all_df.dropna(subset=df_all.columns.tolist()[1:], how='all', inplace=True) 
df = df[(df.iloc[:, 1:] != 0).all(1)] 
all_df['activity'] = all_df['activity'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'^([a-zA-Z]+).*', r'\1', x)) 
all_df.to_csv('all_data.csv', index=False)
```

Here is a sample of the CSV file:

```
activity,kurtosisLenIn,kurtosisTimeIn,madLenIn,madTimeIn,maxLenIn,maxTimeIn,meanLenIn
Fbstt,-2.015559753,10.83952356,546.231405,0.044999868,1500,0.275991,774.4545455
Fbstt,18.22973615,60.34424947,120.5485027,0.017036675,1500,0.493632,1436.301075
Fbstt,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
Fbstt,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
Fbstt,-0.336967713,7.433987655,107.5,0.038565472,417,0.204289,185.3333333
Fbstt,0,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,0.0
Fbstt,0,0,175.1111111,0.005120444,545,0.012801,399.6666667
Fbstt,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Fbstt,-1.895337427,-0.356310433,443.1851852,0.06895037,1332,0.202241,692.3333333
Fbstt,15.84040927,179.5524848,129.7876543,0.006645361,1500,0.586817,1431.288889
```

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to ask a question according to the [ask] page. We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is on-topic here by visiting the [help/on-topic]; asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: Please see the [ask] help page and [The perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) blog post by Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pandas`, try this code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('source.csv')
df = df[(df.iloc[:, 1:] != 0).all(1)]
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: would it be possible to use this code within this please ? where should I insert above in this code ?    
     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56890270/writing-to-csv-file-python-3-7/56890605?noredirect=1#comment100455868_56890605

Comment: regarding that question, try to remove the second line from the bottom where it fills na rows with zeros

Comment: thanks but when I run the above command. I am getting only the column names. no data at all.

Comment: I think its because there are 0.0 values as well. Can we modify the code, so that if a row has 0 or 0.0, 0.00 ...(only zeros even as decimals) to delete those rows from the csv file? thanks

Comment: still the rows that has only 0 and 0.0 values are there. Above is the way I added this code to my previous question code

Comment: @ dralshehri  just to let you know this question was resolved. Thanks